# <select> drop down menu not clickable on android

Tags: android, select, drop-down-menu, webview, clickable

I've read through many posts and "fixes" for this problem but have still not found a solution.  We are using PhoneGap to create a multi-platform app but we are running into a problem on android devices (works fine on iPhone/iPad).  Our  drop down menus are not working, clicking them does nothing.

We are creating all of our pages dynamically by setting the HTML of a content div when a user "goes to a new page".  For example, we are appending the following into our content div for one of our pages

```
<div class="dropdown-padding">
    <select class="trials-dropdown" id="diseaseSite">
        <option value="Any">Any</option>
        <option value="All Cancers">All Cancers</option>
        ...
        <option value="Prostate Cancer">Prostate Cancer</option>
        <option value="Sarcoma">Sarcoma</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What are you using to trigger the page change?

Answer (score 1):

if you have something like this:

```
  <div class='multiselect-wrapper'>
    <div class='multiselect'>Age Range</div>
        <select type='hidden' class='age' id='age' name='age' multiple="">
           <option value='-1'>Age Range</option>
           <option value='6' title='Preyears'>Pre</option>
           <option value='7' title='Kids'>Kids</option>
           <option value='8' title='Tween'</option>
           <option value='9' title='Adult'>Adult</option>
        </select>
   </div>
```

and it is not working on your android (showing the native drawer for the options that you want to pick) then it is probably a CSS issue about your label DIV, in this example it would be ".multiselect". What is missing probably is the "pointer-events" see this for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

If you update your CSS to be something like this:

```
.multiselect{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
```

Then it should work, allowing you to click the select and show the drawer with the multiselect options (basically the native multi checkboxes).

Hoping this works for you.

I worked this with my colleague [Basem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4487191/basem) and it worked for us.

Cheers,

CG.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of this fix from one of my friends who said setting the

```
style.display=block
```

property for this dropdown after you set the HTML dynamically will resolve this issue.

If you have multiple dropdowns then iterate them using

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')
```